# HTML Printing - Different paper sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I have 2 html documents to print 2 different contents. Papers needed for these to html documents are:

1. `A4` (for Printing Cash Bill)
2. `A6` (for Printing Cash Receipt)

Everytime, when printing these, I have to select paper sizes in printer manually. My printer is `Canon LBP2900 Laser Printer`

Is it possible to set default values in html documents or in `css`? I am using Bootstrap V3.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS @page rule.

```
@page {
      size: A4;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page